# Cannot access FileChooser methods

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-8

I can't access FileChooser methods (when I'm trying invoke one of them, my IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3 complains it can't find symbol of these methods). Oddly, class itself is importing fine (I can make object of FileChooser type) I tried to update JDK from 8u211 to 8u231, but that's not worked… So, how to fix that?

```
package sample;

import calculus.LinearRegression;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

import java.io.File;

public class Controller {
    @FXML private TextField x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,y1,y2,y3,y4,y5;
    @FXML private Button choseFile;

    FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
    chooser.getExtensionFilters(); //not works

    @FXML protected void calculateLinearRegression(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        float[][] x = new float[5][2];
        float[] y = new float[5];
        x[0] = new float[]{Float.parseFloat(x1.getText()), 1};
        y[0] = Float.parseFloat(y1.getText());
        x[1] = new float[]{Float.parseFloat(x2.getText()), 1};
        y[1] = Float.parseFloat(y2.getText());
        x[2] = new float[]{Float.parseFloat(x3.getText()), 1};
        y[2] = Float.parseFloat(y3.getText());
        x[3] = new float[]{Float.parseFloat(x4.getText()), 1};
        y[3] = Float.parseFloat(y4.getText());
        x[4] = new float[]{Float.parseFloat(x5.getText()), 1};
        y[4] = Float.parseFloat(y5.getText());
        LinearRegression regression = new LinearRegression(x,y);
        Alert d = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
        d.setContentText("Approximated to y="+regression.result[0]+"x+"+regression.result[1]);
        d.showAndWait();
    }

    @FXML protected void openFileChooser(ActionEvent actionEvent){
            File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(((Button)actionEvent.getTarget()).getParent().getScene().getWindow());
        };
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll be fine once you move it to a method/constructor/initializer block or initialize a field with the return value. (In this case a constructor or a non-`static` initializer block seems to be the way to go.)